# Cannot resolve the symbol HttpPatch while using import statement 'import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPatch'

Tags: http, http-patch

Cannot resolve the symbol HttpPatch, while using import statement :

```
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPatch
```

I also added required dependencies in gradle file. I actually want to make patch call and send JSON object as a body.

I am new to android, please ignore if my way of putting question is wrong. Help with answer. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: did you find any solution to above question or any alternative?